# What are the various duty stations on the Enterprise NCC-1701's bridge?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, uss-enterprise

I can identify the Captain's duty station, Navigation, Communications, and the Science Officers console, and there are often Security personal standing guard near the turbolift. What are the other duty stations on Enterprise NCC-1701's bridge? [image: Bridge] [image: Bridge2]

Comment: I realize the first pic is from the series pilot, but the Bridge design appears to be the same as the rest of the series.

Comment: Your title is asking about the Enterprise D (*Next Generation*), yet your screenshot and illustration are of the original Enterprise (the ship from *The Original Series*, with no "D" on vessel registry).  I am assuming you are asking about the original vessel.

Comment: @Praxis Thank you. Yes. I got booted. Reviewed and edited accordingly.

Comment: @MajorStackings Well, even starfleet computers had their issues getting the right ship, i.e. the *N-C-C-1-7-0-1. No bloody A - B - C - or D!* :)

Comment: @Mario or even now, no bloody E

Comment: @MrDobilina Don't start with that or you'll have to go till at least J. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A schematic of the stations are included in the subchapter [Main Bridge](http://www.haynes.co.uk/enterprise/PDFs/H4941spread2.pdf) of the NCC 1701 within the book *Star Trek: U.S.S. Enterprise Haynes Manual* (Robinson and Riley, 2011). The stations are, from the linked page:

> Working clockwise from the main viewscreen the
>   consoles were: defense subsystems, weapons subsystems,
>   navigation subsystems, science, and communications.

Then there is the turbolift, continuing in a clockwise fashion from the turbolift back to the main viewscreen was the Engineering station, Environmental and Engineering subsystems and Bridge support systems, which according to the Haines manual:

> The stations on
>   the other side of the turbolift, relating to engineering
>   and environmental systems, weren’t always manned
>   during routine operations, their functions being
>   primarily controlled from main engineering

*Incidently, while the [Haynes manual](http://www.haynes.co.uk/enterprise/) where this answer came from is non-canon, it is a licensed source:*

> This Haynes Manual is fully authorized by CBS and technical consultant Michael Okuda, who spent 20 years working on *STAR TREK* TV series and movies.

Comment: I think this is just fanon, right? Is anything in here (apart from what the OP mentioned) backed up by canon or even licensed non-canon sources?

Comment: @Kidburla To be honest, I am not sure (am new to this)

Comment: @Kidburla I have included a reference to a Haines guide - but like I said, I am not sure what you would consider as 'canon'.

Comment: Generally, canon = television series and movies, licensed non-canon = anything licensed by CBS/Paramount (most mass released products), fanon = things produced by fans. I thought that the blueprints website was just fanon, but the Haynes manual should at least be licensed. Thanks for your clarification.

Comment: In The Making of Star Trek the bridge layout is the same as the Haynes Manual.

Answer (score 3):

There's already a great answer here, but I thought I'd add some other diagrams. These, and many, many other bridge schematics, were created by Tobias Weinmann and can be viewed at www.cygnus-x1.net under the Blueprints and Schematics tab. I've included one for *Enterprise* under Pike in the TOS episode "The Cage" and one for the *Enterprise* under Kirk for the bulk of TOS.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Though my memory on this is from the original viewing of the series, (circa 1966-68) the stations were from turbo lift engineering, and aux-engineering,  (environmental controls), a sub-station of environmental controls for defensive measures against intruders (anesthesizen gas pumped into the bridge by Khan in "The Space Seed"), view screen. The stations clockwise from the main view screen were never shown as being manned that often, and certainly never expressly referred to. It seems to me that these could be auxiliary stations that could be assigned for multiple uses. Sulu was at conn (helm), but he frequently fired weapons as did Chekov et,al. at the navigation station. It always seemed that all of the bridge stations were designed to allow multi-tasking (before it became an actual present participle). To be honest I don't think the people who produced the show knew or caried, so long as the looked good, and of course futuristic. Although, there is an anecdote related by George Takei that some director told him to press a certain set of buttons to accomplish some order. Takei told him that certain other buttons did that function, and  the director's instructions did something else." So, it seems to be anyone's choice what all of the stations were for. Hope this is some help.